# SSAS MDX query result only 2 dimensional (matrix), can it be "3" (pivot table)?

Tags: multidimensional-array, ssas, mdx

I am facing a problem, but maybe it is a nature of MDX,

I have lets say on Rows different Product Models, and I want to see couple of measures but for more than one period.

Currently, as the results have matrix-nature, I am only able to either:
Have Product Models on rows and measures on columns, but then I can see these results only for one period (WHERE condition) or:

I can have again Product Models on Rows and date dimension on Columns, but then, I only can see one measure (default measure, or the one specified in the WHERE condition),

Is there some possibility to get results more like a "pivot" nature, so that I can see all three dimensions (Product models, measures, date) in the same time? And purely with MDX expression.

Thank you very much

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create multidimentional pivot tables with mdx by also corssjoining many different dimensions within an axis:

to illustrate with your example:

```
SELECT

[Measures].[Internet Sales Amount] * [Customer].[Customer Geography].[Country] ON 0,

[Product].[Model Name].[Model Name] * [Date].[Calendar].[Calendar Year]  ON 1
FROM [Adventure Works]
```

Philip,

Comment: please one more rather newbie question, but is there some reserved word/way how to hide/not show the "all" results? I get results not only for combined dimensions, but also for only one dimension where 2.nd dimension simply is "all"

Comment: edit: I get it now, this is not the problem with crossjoin rather than  the dimension itself which is containing the "All" attribute as well. I still wonder how not to show it..my query: SELECT {[Measures].[AFR],[Measures].[IB],[Measures].[IC All]} ON COLUMNS,
   {[Dim_Product_Models_new].[PLA].&[PSBM]} * {[Dim_Product_Models_new].[Warranty Group].members} *   {[Dim Dates_new].[Date Full].&[2013-02-01]:[Dim Dates_new].[Date Full].&[2014-01-01]} ON ROWS
FROM [cub_dashboard_spares]

Comment: got it. i just needed to write - [Dim_Product_Models_new].[Warranty Group].[All] into the statement so that ALL member is excluded.